# Showing Image in Kivy doesn't work with path reference in Python

Tags: python, kivy

I want to display a picture on the screen and it works when I put the Path directly in the Image source. But when I try to reference it through root Path to python it does not work somehow. I have done it multiple other times but I have never run into this problem. I am pretty new to programming so there is probably an easy solution. Here are the parts of code that it is about.

py file:

```
class SingleTrainingPlan(Screen):
    path_i = StringProperty()

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(SingleTrainingPlan, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def show_training(self, r):
    training_path = []
    self.path_i = "training_programs/Unknown-1.jpeg"
    print(self.path_i)


class TrainingApp(App):
    singletrainingplan = SingleTrainingPlan()


TrainingApp().run()
```

kv file:

```
ScreenManager:
    MainWindow:
    TrainingPlans:
    SingleTrainingPlan:


<MainWindow>
    name: "mainwindow"

    RelativeLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 1, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size

            Color:
                rgb: 0, 0, 0

            Line:
                width: 2
                points: 0, self.height*.96, self.width, self.height*.96


        RelativeLayout:
            size_hint: 1, .05
            pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": .95}

            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgb: 0, 1, 0

                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size

            Label:
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .1, "y": 0}
                text: "Hello Till"
                color: (0, 0, 0)

        SideBar:


        CurrentStats:


<TrainingPlans>
    name: "trainingplans"

    FloatLayout:
        size: self.width, self.height

        Label:
            size_hint: .1, .05
            pos_hint: {"x": .8, "top": .1}
            text: "Plans"

        Label:
            font_size: 24
            pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": .3}
            text: "SUGGONMYNUTS"

        Button:
            size_hint: .1, .05
            pos_hint: {"x": .1, "y": .1}
            text: "Back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "mainwindow"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"


        Button:
            background_normal: "training_programs/unknown.jpeg"
            size_hint: .2, .2
            pos_hint: {"x": .7, "y": .7}



<SideBar>
    size_hint: .25, .95
    pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": 0}

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0, 0, 1

        Rectangle:
            size: self.size

    Button:
        text: "Home"
        size_hint: .8, .15
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .9}

    Button:
        text: "TrainingPlans"
        size_hint: .8, .1
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .1}
        on_release: app.root.current = "trainingplans"

    Button:
        text: "BALLS"
        size_hint: .8, .1
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .25}

    Button:
        text: "BALLS"
        size_hint: .8, .1
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .4}

    Button:
        text: "BALLS"
        size_hint: .8, .1
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .55}

    Button:
        text: "BALLS"
        size_hint: .8, .1
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .7}

<CurrentStats>
    name: "currentstats"

    RelativeLayout:
        size_hint: .75, .95
        pos_hint: {"x": .25, "y": 0}

        canvas:

            Color:
                rgb: 1, 0, 0

            Rectangle:
                size: self.size

            Color:
                rgb: 0, 0, 0

            Line:
                width: 2
                points: self.width * 0.55, self.height - 2, self.width * 0.55, 0

            Line:
                width: 2
                points: 2, self.height * .9, self.width, self.height * .9

        FloatLayout:

            Label:
                text: "Your Progress this Week:"
                font_size: 24
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                text_size: self.size
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .52, "center_y": 1.43}
                halign: "left"


            Label:
                text: "Weight Training"
                font_size: 20
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                text_size: self.size
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .52, "center_y": 1.23}
                align: "center"

            Label:
                text: "Endurance Training"
                font_size: 20
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                text_size: self.size
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .52, "center_y": 1.03}
                halign: "left"

            Label:
                text: "Coordination"
                font_size: 20
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                text_size: self.size
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .52, "center_y": .83}
                halign: "left"

            Label:
                text: "Games"
                font_size: 20
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                text_size: self.size
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .52, "center_y": .63}
                halign: "left"



        Label:
            text: "Next Trainings"
            font_size: 20
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 1.08, "center_y": 1.43}
            color: (0, 0, 0)
            text_size: self.size
            halign: "left"

        Label:
            text: root.sgst_tr_1
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 1.08, "center_y": 1.23}
            color: (0, 0, 0)
            text_size: self.size
            halign: "left"

        Label:
            text: root.sgst_tr_2
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 1.08, "center_y": 1.03}
            color: (0, 0, 0)
            text_size: self.size
            halign: "left"

        Label:
            text: root.sgst_tr_3
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 1.08, "center_y": .83}
            color: (0, 0, 0)
            text_size: self.size
            halign: "left"

        Label:
            text: root.sgst_tr_4
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 1.08, "center_y": .63}
            color: (0, 0, 0)
            text_size: self.size
            halign: "left"


        RelativeLayout:
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 1, "center_y": 0}
            size_hint: .1, .8


            Button:
                text: "Delete"
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                size_hint: 1, .1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0, "center_y": 1.42}
                on_release: root.destroy_first_suggested_training()

            Button:
                text: "Delete"
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                size_hint: 1, .1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0, "center_y": 1.16}
                on_release: root.destroy_second_suggested_training()

            Button:
                text: "Delete"
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                size_hint: 1, .1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0, "center_y": .9}
                on_release: root.destroy_third_suggested_training()

            Button:
                text: "Delete"
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                size_hint: 1, .1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0, "center_y": .64}
                on_release: root.destroy_fourth_suggested_training()



            Button:
                text: "Show"
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                size_hint: 1, .1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0, "center_y": 1.33}
                on_release:
                    app.singletrainingplan.show_training(1)
                    app.root.current = "singletrainingplan"

    
<SingleTrainingPlan>
    name: "singletrainingplan"

    FloatLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 1, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size

        Image:
            source: root.path_i


        Button:
            text: "back"
            size_hint: .1, .1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .1, "center_y": .1}
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "mainwindow"




`
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Your `kv` file is incomplete and affects the answer.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I just put the whole kv file online. I really don't know what causes the problem so i couldn't minimalism it. But the most important Part is on the Bottom. i don't know how much the top part affects the rest. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your `kv`:

```
            on_release:
                app.singletrainingplan.show_training(1)
                app.root.current = "singletrainingplan"
```

you are referencing `app.singletrainingplan` which is a reference to an instance of `SingleTrainingPlan`. However, that instance is not the one that is displayed in your `App`. The `SingleTrainingPlan` instance that is displayed is created  when the `kv` file is loaded. You can access the correct `SingleTrainingPlan` instance like this:

```
            on_release:
                app.root.get_screen('singletrainingplan').show_training(1)
                app.root.current = "singletrainingplan"
```

And the line of code in your `App`:

```
singletrainingplan = SingleTrainingPlan()
```

can be deleted.